# Scale SVG when it hits the logo Div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg, sass

We have a SVG wave design that appears under the navigation on a WordPress site. The SVG is floating right currently and would like to have the SVG begin to scale down with the browser once it hits the div the logo is in. Essentially, we would like the SVG to cover everything in the navigation but never cover the logo even when scaling down. Is that even possible?

See http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/ for live example and code

Comment: i can not understand your question, show some code or do a `view source` and use `pastebin` to show code

Comment: Have you tried maybe putting the logo and the SVG in two column grid (maybe 3:9)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.homepage-svg {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 180px;
  float: right;
}
```

updated your style sheet (css) using above code. It will be work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a solution to this with pure CSS other than approximating the effect with percentage widths or varying media queries for screen size. However, this is entirely possible with Javascript by adjusting the SVG size based on screen and logo width. Here's a quick implementation using JS based on your current HTML and CSS:

```
var wave = document.getElementsByClassName("homepage-svg")[0];
var logo = document.getElementsByClassName("site-branding")[0];

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; //Support for different browsers
    var logoWidth = logo.offsetWidth;

    var maxSVGWidth = 1200; //1200px was obtained from your CSS

    //If the screen is too small to show both the wave and the logo at full size (with no overlap), decrease the width of the wave
    if(screenWidth < maxSVGWidth + logoWidth) {
        wave.style.width = screenWidth - logoWidth + "px";
    }
});
```

I tested this on the link you shared (in Chrome) and it worked, but is quite rough and doesn't account for the initial page load since it only runs on a window resize. However, it should be fairly easy to make any necessary adjustments.

Hope this helps!  :)